# javascript button innerHTML

Tags: javascript, button, random, innerhtml

I made 4 buttons with random options of answer to a question in Javascript.

A user has to choose 1 option as an answer.
How do I have to write the code in order to check if the button's value(or innerHTML) is matching the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

When listening to the click event you can pass through the event and fetch the target from there. 
Then you just collect the innerHTML

`event.target.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button name="answers" id="first" truly="true">first</button>
<button name="answers" id="second">second</button>
<button name="answers" id="third">third</button>

$("button[name=answers]").click(function(){
  if($(this).attr("truly")) alert("congratilations")
})
```